# ZF2: Using JSON-RPC without MVC?

Tags: zend-framework2, json-rpc

It is stated in the ZF2 documentation, as well as by Matthew Weier O'Phinney's blog, that:

> Many developers want to stick this in their MVC application directly,
>   in order to have pretty URLs. However,  the framework team typically
>   recommends against this. When serving APIs, you want responses to
>   return as quickly as possible, and as the servers basically
>   encapsulate the Front Controller and MVC patterns in their design,
>   there's no good reason to duplicate processes and add processing
>   overhead.

It is recommended that you put the server endpoints in the public directory structure. For example, you might have /public/some-api.php that instantiates and runs the Zend RPC Server. But I have already created this dope module in which I have a bunch of classes and a config file that lays out the dependency injection, factories, etc for creating the classes.

Soo... how do I leverage that code in my RPC server, without putting it into a MVC controller?

Thanks!
Adam

Comment: That sounds like it could be old news. Got a link to that blog post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it. I have this broken out into a few files, but you can put all this in your public root directory, something like rpc-service.php:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager,
    Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig;

class Bootstrap {
    /** @var  ServiceManager */
    private static $serviceManager;

    private static function _go() {
        chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

        require __DIR__ . '/../init_autoloader.php';

        $config = include __DIR__ . '/../config/application.config.php';

        $serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
        $serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $config);
        $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();

        self::$serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return ServiceManager
     */
    public static function getServiceManager() {
        if (!self::$serviceManager)
            self:: _go();

        return self::$serviceManager;
    }
}

$sm = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();

use Zend\Json\Server\Server,
    Zend\Json\Server\Smd,

$jsonRpc = new Server();
$jsonRpc->setClass($sm->get('Some\Class'));
$jsonRpc->getRequest()->setVersion(Server::VERSION_2);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    echo $jsonRpc->getServiceMap()->setEnvelope(Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);
}
else {
    $jsonRpc->handle();
}
```

As you can see, I'm using the Service Manager! Yay. All is right in the world.